Scraping subreddit from inception to present
I'm currently working on retrieving data from a subreddit, aiming to capture all posts since its inception. However, I'm encountering a limitation where I can only access information for the latest 1000 posts. Below is the code I'm currently using:
Is there a workaround or alternative method that would allow me to fetch all posts from the subreddit, starting from its earliest entries? Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.
subreddit = reddit.subreddit("AfricanCichlids")
%%time
def scrape_subreddit_data(subreddit):
    data = {
        'Title': [],
        'Author': [],
        'Upvotes': [],
        'Downvotes': [],
        'Score': [],
        'Number of Comments': [],
        'Creation Time': [],
        'Is NSFW': [],
        'Is Spoiler': [],
        'Is Locked': [],
        'Is Archived': [],
        'Subreddit Subscribers': [],
        'Subreddit Active Users': [],
        'Subreddit Creation Time': [],
        'Comments': []
        
        # Add more fields as needed
    }
    
    for submission in subreddit.new(limit=None): # Paginate through all posts from the start
        data['Title'].append(submission.title)
        data['Author'].append(submission.author)
        data['Upvotes'].append(submission.score)
        data['Downvotes'].append(submission.downs)
        data['Score'].append(submission.ups - submission.downs)
        data['Number of Comments'].append(submission.num_comments)
        data['Creation Time'].append(pd.to_datetime(submission.created_utc, unit='s'))
        data['Is NSFW'].append(submission.over_18)
        data['Is Spoiler'].append(submission.spoiler)
        data['Is Locked'].append(submission.locked)
        data['Is Archived'].append(submission.archived)
        data['Subreddit Subscribers'].append(submission.subreddit.subscribers)
        data['Subreddit Active Users'].append(submission.subreddit.accounts_active)
        data['Subreddit Creation Time'].append(pd.to_datetime(submission.subreddit.created_utc, unit='s'))

        
        # Rate limiting: sleep for a short duration between requests
        time.sleep(2)  # Sleep for 1 second between requests
        
        submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
        comments = []
        for comment in submission.comments.list():
            comments.append(comment.body)
        data['Comments'].append(comments)
        # Add more fields as needed
    
    return data

# Scrape data from subreddit
data = scrape_subreddit_data(subreddit)

# Convert data to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


This is a Reddit API limit, you can't view more than 1000 posts even through the official website.
If you are a reddit moderator, you can try pushshift.
Otherwise, you'll have to look through the dumps, which include the top 40 thousands subreddits (2005-06 to 2023-12).
for the latest months, you can search Watchful1's profile here.
